# How to create a WPF Path which stretches in places

Tags: wpf, canvas, pathgeometry

I'd like to create a WPF control for a window tab, and I want it to have a particular shape. Something like this;

```
      +------------------------------+
      |                              |
*     |                              |
      |                              |
   +--+                              +--+
6  |                                    |  6
   +------------------------------------+   
     6       stretching section       6
```

So the little tabs at the bottom left and bottom right are fixed size; 6x6, roughly. But now I want the centre section to stretch out to the width of whatever container I slap it into.

I'm using a Path object at the moment, but I can't figure out how to get a stretching section, or even if Path is the right way to go.

Can anyone suggest the best way to create this kind of half-stretchable shape?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I did the stretching part in my app by creating a "StretchStackPanel" that inherits from StackPanel. The class looks like this:

```
public class StretchStackPanel : StackPanel
{
    public static DependencyProperty StretchDependencyProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("Stretch", typeof(StretchMode), typeof(StretchStackPanel));

    protected override Size MeasureOverride(Size availableSize)
    {
        var baseSize = base.MeasureOverride(availableSize);

        if (availableSize.Width != double.PositiveInfinity && (Stretch & StretchMode.Horizontal) == StretchMode.Horizontal )
        {
            baseSize.Width = availableSize.Width;    
        }
        if (availableSize.Height != double.PositiveInfinity && (Stretch & StretchMode.Vertical) == StretchMode.Vertical)
        {
            baseSize.Height = availableSize.Height;
        }

        return baseSize;
    }

    protected override Size ArrangeOverride(Size finalSize)
    {
        var baseSize = base.ArrangeOverride(finalSize);

        if ((Stretch & StretchMode.Horizontal) == StretchMode.Horizontal )
        {
            baseSize.Width = finalSize.Width;    
        }

        if ((Stretch & StretchMode.Vertical) == StretchMode.Vertical)
        {
            baseSize.Height = finalSize.Height;
        }
        return baseSize;
    }

    [Category("Layout")]
    public StretchMode Stretch
    {
        get
        {
            return (StretchMode)GetValue(StretchDependencyProperty);
        }
        set
        {
            SetValue(StretchDependencyProperty, value);
        }
    }
}
```

What you want is a Grid with 2 rows. The content of the top row should have it's horizontal alignment set to center. the content of the bottom row should be a StretchStackPanel.

Answer (score 3):

Why not create two different widgets? One for the centre section and another for the stretchable section. Then stick them together in another container to form a unified control.

Comment: Unfortunately I have to put a complex fill into the shape, and put a stroke around it. Three controls would have three different strokes, and the fill would be badly aligned.

Answer (score 2):

I think you should override the MeasureOverride method in your control and get DesiredSize of your content (by calling Measure method on Content/Children). Then you can create your Path based on this size.